# Accounts tab in SO

Tags: support, user-accounts

Where is the accounts tab located in SO/SF/SU/META?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Click on your name at the top of the page to access your profile. The accounts tab is the one on the far right.

Answer (score 3):

The Accounts tab is no longer visible under your site profile.

In your profile summary, there will be an Accounts section, which will list the first few accounts, but the *View More* link with take you to the full *Accounts* tab in SE.

[Alternatively, if you click on your profile, select the *Network Profile* link, and from their you can get click on the *Accounts* link to get to the same destination]

Comment: Why did it move?

Comment: No idea - I had the Accounts Tab in my StackOverflow profile as my homepage. A few days ago the Accounts tab disappeared, and it went to my SO Profile Summary page; and then it changed to the same link redirects to StackExchange Accounts tab.

Answer (score 1):

Now accounts tab is changed.

Anybody who don't know how to go to accounts tab now:

1. Go to your Network profile(SE account). [image: Network profile]
2. Then got to accounts tab same as which was present previously in each accounts tab.[image: accounts tab]